# How to play sound at precise moments on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, timing

I'm working on creating a simple metronome on the iPhone. What the app does right now is to run a timer, entering the timer's function every <strike>1/1000th</strike> of second. Then it checks the current time vs time of starting the app (I'm using `CACurrentMediaTime()` function).

```
CFTimeInterval currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
if (self.beatingStartTime == 0) {
    self.beatingStartTime = currentTime;
}
if ( (currentTime - self.beatingStartTime) >= self.timeIntevalBetweenTicks * self.internalTimerCounter ) {
    self.internalTimerCounter ++;
    // ...
}
```

If there is a good moment to play audio, the code using OpenAL to play it gets fired.

Basicly that's it. I checked the sounds played when running both in simulator as well as on 2 devices (iPad and jailbroken iPhone 3GS) and there is a problem - when I recorded the sound and reviewed the waveform in [`Reaper`](http://www.reaper.fm/) software, some sounds play a bit too late, and some of them - bit too early (even I could understand the "too late" part, I don't really get how it can play earlier then it should - since the app checks the number of seconds every time, it basicly can't be ealier then specified time - yet it is, according to my recods).

At the same time there are some metronome apps that are known for being "rock-solid" when it comes to timing, so I guess there is a way. I just wonder what I'm missing...

---

**edit**: Changing timer call from 1/1000th second to, for example 1/100th doesn't help.

**edit 2**: When I switched from timer to threads (and I put the thread to sleep for specified time) I still get a strange behavior. The tempo moves around and while I could understand a little lag and playing some sounds too late, the problem is some of them do play **too early** - it means time distance between 2 beats is less then the time that should pass.

The diffrence is about 3%, which translates to about 10-15 miliseconds, which is quite a lot for me. Anyone got an idea why the sound can play earlier? I tried it both on iPhone simulator and on iPad actual device, and my only guess is there's something wrong with the timer - `CACurrentMediaTime()` returning more seconds that it should. Is it even possible?

Comment: Why are you using OpenAL rather than a simple AVAudioPlayer? (Does your metronome require positional audio?)

Comment: Nope. But I had similar problem (or, even worse) with AVAudioPlayer before, when I used that. And I found an advice to use OpenAL instead, since it's best at playing sound at particular moments (synchronized with particle game frame, etc). - this blog entry http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/ mentiones "For better control of the sound, you will require either openAL or audioUnits or the audioQueue").

Comment: @kender, Also, you can't call a timer 1000 times a second, and ask it to respond.  You're asking for a lot of trouble, which is why it may seem like it never hits it's mark.  Even if you set the metronome to 16th notes at a tempo of 240, you only need a timer with a resolution of 0.015625 seconds.  You won't get milli-second precision on the iphone without running your own c-libraries, and then it's iffy.

Comment: @Kender, have you tried [NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0]; 

If you prioritize the thread, it should stabilize your results somewhat, however I'm not convinced using Core Animation to handle your timing is the way to go. Animation doesn't need to be as precise as what you're using it for.

Comment: What to use then? System time is even less stable (and can be shifted on iPhone, when it syncs with the network, for example...)

Comment: I'd say you just have to trust the API (it's been around for almost 10 years). I think it's safe to assume that the system date isn't altered while an application is running. Keeping NSDate stable is Apple's job, and if it wasn't stable, they'd have a lot of angry people coming after them. As well, core animation would have the same underlying dependencies as NSDate, so there's no reason to assume that one is more stable than the other.

Comment: I don't think this would be giving any 'angry customers'. Time shifts caused by network time sync are usually small. They  happen on desktop PC/Mac, and I don't really see lot of people getting too angry about it...

Comment: in this case I was referring to developers. :) if they couldn't rely on the Date/Time APIs to give consistent results, it'd be bad news for Apple!

Comment: if you are concerned about date changes, consider overriding - (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application in your application delegate

Answer (score 5):

Try using an NSSound, and load it up as an instance variable and don't release it unless your metronome isn't running. Delays can be caused by loading the file into memory on the loop. The other thing to consider is that a metronome probably doesn't need to poll every 1/1000th of a second. If you do it less often, you're less likely to saturate the CPU and you might get more consistent results.

Lastly, check out how Apple's demo works: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Metronome/Introduction/Intro.html

Might give you a better idea how to accomplish what you're trying to do :)

Comment: Right now I'm using OpenAL and my sounds are read into instance variables on metronome start, so they don't really need to be read from file on each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is **COCOS DENSHION** which is a simple reliable easy to use sound library, that we have found solves all problems.

I (just personally) don't like "Cocos2D" but you can just take and use CocosDenshion.

Secondly -- 1000th of a second is ridiculous for a timer.  Just totally forget it.

Thirdly -- AVAudioPlayer is worthless as you found.

## Note - "ObjectAL" is a new, perhaps better, alternative

to CocosDenshion.  Check it out.